# Why compile running multiple times - Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the following snippet, I want to ask that if compile phase runs only once for all the instances of a directive, then why am I seeing console.log("compile") run 5 times? It should have run only once? Isn't it?

```js
//module declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.name = "Joseph";
});

//app declaration
app.directive('myStudent',function(){
 return{
  template: "Hi! Dear!! {{name}}<br/>",
  compile: function(elem, attr){
   console.log("compile");
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<my-student></my-student> 
<my-student></my-student> 
<my-student></my-student> 
<my-student></my-student> 
<my-student></my-student> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Comment: its for each instance of it. `compile != $compile`

Comment: Can you explain it a bit?

Answer (score 1):

HTML compilation happens in three phases:

1. $compile traverses the DOM and matches directives.

   If the compiler finds that an element matches a directive, then the    directive is added to the list of directives that match the DOM element. A single element may match multiple directives.
2. Once all directives matching a DOM element have been identified, the compiler sorts the directives by their priority.

   Each directive's compile functions are executed. Each compile function has a chance to modify the DOM. Each compile function returns a link function. These functions are composed into a "combined" link function, which invokes each directive's returned link function.
3. $compile links the template with the scope by calling the combined linking function from the previous step. This in turn will call the linking function of the individual directives, registering listeners on the elements and setting up $watchs with the scope as each directive is configured to do.

Comment: It still not answers why my compile ran 5 times?

Comment: The compile phase

When the DOM is loaded Angular starts the compile phase, where it traverses the markup top-down, and calls compile on all directives. Graphically, we could express it like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZPOm.png


For nested directives

Note: The following does not apply to directives that render their children in their link function. Quite a few Angular directives do so (like ngIf, ngRepeat, or any directive with transclude). These directives will natively have their link function called before their child directives compile is called.

Answer (score 1):

From Angular documentation "What are Directives?
At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element (e.g. via event listeners), or even to transform the DOM element and its children."

So when angular compiles the html, it traverse through the mark up and whenever it finds `<my-student></my-student>` mark up it will try attaching "the specific behaviour". To get the specific behavior it need to compile the directive each time since each instance of directives might have different attributes or parameters.